# Compute percentile for a given value

Tags: r

In a dataframe I have a column with the total score on a questionnaire. I want to add a column in which, for each total score, there is the relative percentile with respect to the data distribution. How can I do it in R?

Comment: [This should be helpful](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Finding-percentile-of-a-value-from-an-empirical-distribution-td4284462.html). In short, look up the ecdf() function.

Answer (score 13):

Let `x` be the data.frame, and let `x$score` be the column of the total score. You could add a column of percentile by

```
x$percentile <- ecdf(x$score)(x$score)
```

Now the data.frame `x` has an additional column `percentile`, which is what you want.